# Receive Not-sends in entry source data extention upon triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, triggered-send, transactional-messaging-api

We are trying to set up a transactional triggered send using a Transactional API Event in journeybuilder, that also includes the not-sends in the entry source data extension.

Apparently this is the case for promotional mails but not for transactional ones. The entry source gets filled and includes all the data but when the mail is not-send the record does not show in the entry source data extension.

We already have set-up a call-back solution to retrieve the not-sends in a different data extension. This includes the status/messageKey/email/... of the sends but not the fields that where in the 'body' when triggered like amount/firstname/address/... We need all of this info.

Is there a way to enable the not-sends to enter the entry source data extension? Or can anyone think of a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the email sending time sensitive (real-time, nearly real-time)?

Comment: Hi Rachid, Thanks for your comment! We prefer the send out in nearly real-time but the retrieving of the status could have a couple of hours delay.

Comment: There is probably a better workaround, but the only one I can think of right now is: Replacing your API Event Journey by a strandard DE entry source: Create a DE linked to a journey, inject your contacts into this DE and have an automation that injects these contacts into a journey. Since it's nearly real-time, you can check articles on how to schedule an automation to run every x minutes.